# Resume Maven build from IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When building my maven multi-module project in IntelliJ, how can I resume the build from the last failed module?

From command line one would use the "-rf" parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not find this easily, so decided to document it here.

How to resume the build from the last failed module onwards:

**In the "Run"-Window, there is a button on the left with the tooltip "Resume build from specified module"**. The button is enabled if the build failed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Source of answer and screenshot: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81112